# merge cells of arrays in math mode

Tags: support, mathjax

Is there a way to type an array with certain cells merged in math mode on StackExchange?

I tried to use **multirow** and **multicolumn** commands within **array** environment, but apparently MathJax does not support those.

Comment: You may find these threads relevant (esp. links given in comments): [Loading LaTeX packages](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13491/loading-latex-packages), [What latex packages are used this site?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11864/what-latex-packages-are-used-this-site)

Comment: Just for background. MathJax currently lacks such macros because our underlying MathML implementation does not yet support the corresponding column/row-spanning constructs. Once these are done, such macros are easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too few reputation points to edit someone else's post, so I post a follow-up to [Américo Tavares answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21002/152299) as my own answer — here's a cell split into rows

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
 a^2-b^2 & 
 \begin{array}{ccc} 1+i & 1-i & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
 \end{array} \\\hline  
 \color{green}{\begin{array}{c}a-b \\  a+b
 \end{array}} & \sqrt {2}
\end{array}
$$

```
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
 a^2-b^2 & 
 \begin{array}{ccc} 1+i & 1-i & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
 \end{array} \\\hline  
 \color{green}{
 \begin{array}{c}a-b \\  a+b \end{array}
 } & \sqrt {2}
\end{array}
$$
```

The real problem is cross-row or cross-column alignment:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
 a^2-b^2 & 
 \begin{array}{ccc} 1+i & 1-i & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
 \end{array} \\\hline  
 \begin{array}{c}
\color{green}{1+\cfrac 1 {1+\cfrac 1 {1+\cfrac 1\dots}} } \\ \color{blue}{aaaaaaa}
 \end{array} & 
 \begin{array}{c}
\color{green}{bbbbbbb} \\ \color{blue}{2+\cfrac 2 {2+\cfrac 2 {2+\cfrac 2\dots}} }
 \end{array}
\end{array}
$$

```
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
 a^2-b^2 & 
 \begin{array}{ccc} 1+i & 1-i & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
 \end{array} \\\hline  
 \begin{array}{c}
\color{green}{1+\cfrac 1 {1+\cfrac 1 {1+\cfrac 1\dots}} } \\ \color{blue}{aaaaaaa}
 \end{array} & 
 \begin{array}{c}
\color{green}{bbbbbbb} \\ \color{blue}{2+\cfrac 2 {2+\cfrac 2 {2+\cfrac 2\dots}} }
 \end{array}
\end{array}
$$
```

Answer (score 4):

You might split cells instead by using nested arrays, as in the following example

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
a^2-b^2 & 
 \begin{array}{ccc} 1+i & 1-i & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
 \end{array} \\\hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}a-b &  a+b
 \end{array} & \sqrt {2}
\end{array}
$$

It is generated by

`$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
a^2-b^2 & 
 \begin{array}{ccc} 1+i & 1-i & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
 \end{array} \\\hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}a-b &  a+b
 \end{array} & \sqrt {2}
\end{array}
$$`